# How to Run an 'dd' Command Through ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, shell-exec

I'm currently programming an site that has an function that needs to make and PHP ajax request. On the PHP side, I need to run an 'dd' linux command, but the command isn't starting. I'm using PHP shell_exec() function.

Comment: Hard to know how to help without seeing the code that you are using.  Are you sure the AJAX call is triggering? Is the PHP in the AJAX call running?  Please read the help on [how to create an mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it in your question.

Comment: The premise of this question is terrifying.

Comment: Why on earth would you need to execute a dd with PHP, further still with AJAX? (curiosity, not judging)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "gravar.php",
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "text",
    data : {"arquivo" : arquivo, "device" : dev}
})
```

PHP:

```
$device = $_GET["device"];
$arquivo = $_GET["arquivo"];

shell_exec("dd if=/volume1/home/dba/imagens/teste_grava.img of=/dev/sdd1 bs=128M conv=notrunc,noerror");
```